# Как вернуть последний коммит в локальной ветке Git?

Tags: git

Последние команды, которые сделал на ветке #1:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'name_coomit'
```

И забыл сделать

```
git push
```

Потом переключился на ветку #2 и там была сделана команда

```
git pull
```

Когда переключился на ветку #1 я увидел, что не подгрузились нужные файлы. Решил стянуть с облака:

```
git fetch
```

и посмотрев обнаружил, что я не сделал

```
git push
```

Теперь не могу получить состояние на последний коммит в ветке #1.
Даже, находясь на ветке через

```
git log
```

не вижу своего коммита...
Получается, все? Сушить весла?))

Comment: Никакие упомянутые вами команды не могли куда-то деть коммит в ветке #1, значит вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Но в любом случае можно попробовать поискать коммит в каком-нибудь git reflog

Comment: Как посмотреть даты git reflog?

Comment: @andreymal, огромное спасибо тебе! Ты меня спас! Через **git reflog** нашел коммит и переключился на него!